# k-mer counting into R using perfect hashing

Tags: c++, r, math, bioinformatics, rcpp

I worked in DNA K-mers counting and I prepare this formulation to solve the counting using perfect hash table :[link](https://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.3433769.v1).
I used Rcpp API(C++) to integrate the code into R:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
/*
this code can be used with c++ by replacing IntegerVector by std::vector<int>
*/
//************************************************
inline const short int V (const char x){
  switch(x){
  case 'A':case 'a':
    return 0;
    break;
  case 'C':case 'c':
    return 1;
    break;   
  case 'G':case 'g':
    return 2;
    break;
  default:
    return 3;
  break;  
  }

}

inline unsigned int  X0( const std::string A,const int k ,const int n){
  unsigned int  result=0;
  int j=k;
  for( int i=n-1;i>n-k-1;i--) {
    result+= pow(4,k-j)*V(A[i]);
  j--;
  }
  return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
inline IntegerVector kmer4(const std::string A,const int n,const int k)
{

  IntegerVector P(pow(4,k));                  
  int x=X0(A,k,n);                              
  P[x]++;                   
  const int N=pow(4,k-1);               
  for( int i=n-k-1;i>-1;i--){
    x=N*V(A[i])+x/4-x%4/4;
    P[x]++;
  }
  return P;
}
```

There are two questions:

1. Assuming the index x of a kmer,the compliment of x is then (4^k)-x-1. Can we get the reverse using a numeric operation like preceding formula?
2. There are two problems in running time: iteration over the string and vector creation where the k is over then 8. 
   Are there ideas to solve these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Item 1:** I'm not versed in k-mer counting and the definition of `x` is a bit shaky. If you could update your question, then I'll try to address point 1. But, to me it seems as if you just need to use an algorithm that converts from base 10 back to base 4?

**Item 2:** Yes. The iteration that is being performed is suboptimal as you are constantly converting from a `string` to `int` and so on. Moreover, why are the functions being declared `inline`?  Also, how large is the data being passed into `A`?

To address this, we port the string entirely to a `std::vector<int>`. In fact, I would say just port it directly to an `std::vector<int>` and avoid listing that it can be switched to non-rcpp code. Additionally, we opt to use a pass by reference paradigm instead of just a const variable. Lastly, I've cut down on the amount of `inline` declaration.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//************************************************
inline const short int V (const char x){
  switch(x){
  case 'A':case 'a':
    return 0;
    break;
  case 'C':case 'c':
    return 1;
    break;   
  case 'G':case 'g':
    return 2;
    break;
  default:
    return 3;
  break;  
  }

}

std::vector<int> conv_A2V(const std::string & A){
 unsigned int obs = A.length()
 std::vector<int> out(obs);
 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < obs; i++){
   out(i) = V(A[i]);
 }
 return out;
}

unsigned int X0( const std::vector<int> & V_A, const int k, const int n){
  unsigned int  result=0;
  int j=k;
  for( int i=n-1;i>n-k-1;i--) {
    result+= pow(4,k-j)*V_A[i];
  j--;
  }
  return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector kmer4(const std::string A, const int n,const int k)
{
  // Convert
  std::vector<int> V_A = conv_A2V(A);

  IntegerVector P(pow(4,k));                  
  int x=X0(V_A,k,n);                              
  P[x]++;                   
  const int N=pow(4,k-1);               
  for( int i=n-k-1;i>-1;i--){
    x=N*V_A[i]+x/4-x%4/4;
    P[x]++;
  }
  return P;
}
```

Comment: First ,I used inline tag because k-mers calculation is always a prior operation to other function to other tasks

Comment: The problem with **x** is to find the reverse k-mer index using x.The reverse compliment is so,simply calculated

Comment: @MACHERKIME, so what you are saying for point 2: Is the string should have already been converted into a vector of integers/doubles. Writing it as an inline computation is wasteful in my opinion. **For point 1:** The transformation from hash back to standard I think is a bit problematic now that I've had time to sit and look at the initially linked document. In this case, the hash you created is surjective and not a bijective function that uniquely maps one gene expression to a base number.

Comment: think you very much for detail